# Date Adapter for Jaxb2Marshaller Not working

Tags: spring

I am trying to add custom JAXB adapter for date formatting for spring rest controller. Below is my marshalling converter:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller"   class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

Find the below Jaxb2Marshaller:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="...." />
    <property name="adapters">
        <list>
            <bean class="DateTimeConverterAdapter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This adapter never gets called. Same adapter working if I configured using annotation at property level.

I don't want to add the adapter for each and every date property. So i am trying to configure at class level while marshalling. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace  DateTimeConverterAdapter with fqn of this Class .
Fqn = package+Class name

Comment: Hi Pioardi , i have class name with package, but still its not working

Comment: Attention ,you Have 2 Bean with same id. Are you sue that import both Bean in application context?